# Event sourcing domain events (split events)

Tags: c#, domain-driven-design, event-sourcing

I have a question to which I can't find any answer. The scenario looks like this, I have a product which has a couple of fields like name, description, image link, etc. And I have one event `ProductRegistered` with all those fields when I save this to the event store, and when I want to restore aggregate I read this event from the event store and load it to aggregate. When I am doing an update, I have another event `ProductUpdated` which also contains all fields but here is a trick where it only saves only field which was modified. The problem is when I want to modify aggregate and remove or add any property, it throws an exception. So I read about it, and the solution is to split these 2 big events into smaller events. My question is, how I should split it? Should I have one event per field? Because from the endpoint a user can send, let's say, 6 values.

For example, when I register a product should I create events like `ProductRegistered` (with only product Id), `ProductNameChanged` (with the product name) and so on?

Comment: You could have something like this `ProductPropertyChanged(string PropertyName, object oldValue, object newValue)` instead of having an event per property.

Comment: can you elaborate more?

Comment: https://leanpub.com/esversioning

Comment: Also, `ProductChanged` or `ProductNameChanged` doesn't tell you anything about the initial intent. Ask the reason why this product changed and make it explicit in the event name. This would help you to have more business oriented events that mean something from a business point of view.

Answer (score 0):

In general, the best practice is to capture the overall context of what is changing and why, because doing so assists downstream consumers of those events to take action without having to try to reconstruct (likely imperfectly) that context.  Since event sourcing tends to imply CQRS and at least as many read-models as write-models, a more complicated write-model (i.e. more types of events to process) in exchange for less complicated read-models (especially if the read-models can ignore event types which they don't care about) is very often a trade worth making.

There's also no necessary relation between the fields of the aggregate (much less the fields of any particular read-model depending on that aggregate) and the fields of the event: the event's fields should describe the meaning of the change, while the aggregate's fields in the write-model are just capturing what's needed to validate future changes: if the value of `imageLink` never affects whether or not a command to update the `name` is accepted and vice versa, then there's absolutely no need to have `imageLink` and `name` be the same aggregate (you could have two different aggregates with related identifers tracking the name and image link for a product, for instance).